# geeksforgeeks practice: how to take inputs?

Tags: python

I am trying to code in geeksforgeeks practice in this link: http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=282

I use Python. The default code does not have anything. How should I take my inputs and return my outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it work for you :

```
T = int(raw_input()) 
if T < 0 or T > 10 :
    print '0<=T<=10 !'
    exit(0)
for x in xrange(T):
    print '.'.join(str(raw_input()).split('.')[::-1])
```

Comment: That's over-complicated code without any explanation. OP asked for I/O functions, not their use in code. While use cases might be appreciated, they're worthless without any explanation

Answer (score 3):

Cool! I hope you've had fun so far!

Python makes these operations quite easy. Both of the functions you'll want to start with are builtins, so you don't even need to `import` anything!

For inputs, this is probably best handled with [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function prints output.

Answer (score 3):

To take user input, use the `input()` function. For displaying output to user, use the `print()` function

```
originalString = input('Enter The String : ')

# Perform manipulations here

print('Modified String is : ', modifiedString)
```

Comment: Those comments are not part of Python

Comment: Oh lol, was working on a PHP project a bit go and got confused